# Upgrading ASP .NET Ajax produces _header error. Anyone seen this before?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When I upgraded the AjaxControlToolkit.dll via NuGet to the latest version of the toolkit my project now produces an error that tells me there are multiple controls on the page with the ID _header.  I'm unsure what actually gets produced on the client side that has an id of _header but I figured I would ask the stackoverflow community first before I roll back and check things out from the last known working version of code.

Here is the exact stack trace for the error:

```
    EXCEPTION:Multiple controls with the same ID '_header' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.
Data:System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
Stack Trace:   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureNamedControlsTable()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id)
   at System.Web.UI.ControlUtil.FindTargetControl(String controlID, Control control, Boolean searchNamingContainers)
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelControlTrigger.FindTargetControl(Boolean searchNamingContainers)
   at System.Web.UI.AsyncPostBackTrigger.Initialize()
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelTriggerCollection.Initialize()
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.Initialize()
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what the answer ended up being: When updating the ASP .NET Ajax version to the latest version, it is now required to have an ID for each Accordion Pane inside of an Accordion Control.  If you don't assign an ID to them it generates one for you of "_header".  In my case I had more than 1 Accordion Pane so there was indeed more than 1 with the same ID found.  I hope this helps someone else. [Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1457688.aspx) is the post that helped point me in the right direction.  Big Ups CurtWRC :)